# import Control.Monad.Par not working

Tags: haskell

Here are my version info:

cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library

On Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ ghci

GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

Prelude> import Control.Monad.Par

<no location info>: error:
Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Par’
Perhaps you meant
  Control.Monad.Fail (from base-4.9.1.0)
  Control.Monad.Fix (from base-4.9.1.0)
  Control.Monad.RWS (needs flag -package-key mtl-2.2.1@mtl-2.2.1-BLKBelFsPB3BoFeSWSOYj6)
```

Would appreciate any help on how to get Control.Monad.Par to work.

Comment: You need to install the `monad-par` package. Try `cabal install monad-par`.

Comment: Like @DarthFennec said, it is not part of the prelude and must thus be installed locally. I advice you do this in a sandbox (```cabal sandbox init``` at your project root), so your different projects won't complain about broken dependencies and so forth.

Comment: @RobertK, please don't confuse the prelude (a single distinguished module) with the set of packages that ship with GHC.

Comment: @dfeuer That is true, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `Could not find module ‘...’` means you don't have the package installed<sup>1</sup>. You can search the module name on [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) to get the package name, and then do:

```
cabal install [package name]
```

Or if you're using [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) for your project (recommended), you can add the package name to the `build-depends` section in your `*.cabal` file.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>It could also mean you misspelled the module name, the package was installed incorrectly, GHC isn't looking for the package in the place it was installed, or some other weird thing is going on, but I won't go into that.</sup>